# Changing integer values from an if statement not working? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python newb here.  I'm looking to write an if statement that changes an integer value based upon an input and then loops the code.  Unfortunately, I have two problems:

1. When the brightness printers after accepting an input, the value
   that prints is 100 regardless of the input (-10, +10, set to 0, etc)
2. The else statement prints regardless if the user enters a value that
   matches an if statement.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

var = 1
brightness = 100

while var == 1 :  # This constructs an infinite loop

  print 'Brightness is ', brightness

  test1 = raw_input('up, down, on or off? ')

  if test1 == 'up':
     brightness = brightness + 10
     print brightness
  if test1 == 'down':
     brightness = brightness - 10
     print brightness
  if test1 == 'on':
     brightness = 100
     print brightness
  if test1 == 'off':
     brightness = 0
     print brightness
  else:
     print 'Try again'

print "Good bye!"
```

Comment: Use else ifs. It's falling through

Comment: It is working fine in python 2.7.10 although i suggest that use `if..elif..else` instead of so many `if`

Comment: The code runs but I have issues with the #1 and #2 I had mentioned above.

Comment: the `else` only applies to the last `if` statement. You have to use `elif` statements in the middle if you want them all to be evaluated as a single block.

Comment: In my machine it prints appropriate value.

Comment: Your code works perfectly if you replace if with elif in the three conditions between the first if and the last else. Please look at my answer below if you still have doubts. Let me know if it still fails.

Comment: So anytime `test1` is _not_ equal to `'off'` (the last `if` clause), the `else` clause will trigger. An `if` that is not followed by an `else` or `elif` is considered a complete expression.

Comment: @ChaseWestlye: In Python the standard for an infinite loop is just a `while True:`. Much easier, no extra variable needed and if later in your coding you feel the need to break out of the loop you can use the `break` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var = 1
brightness = 100

while var == 1 :  # This constructs an infinite loop

print 'Brightness is ', brightness

test1 = raw_input('up, down, on or off? ')

if test1 == 'up':
    brightness = brightness + 10
    print brightness
elif test1 == 'down':
    brightness = brightness - 10
    print brightness
elif test1 == 'on':
    brightness = 100
    print brightness
elif test1 == 'off':
    brightness = 0
    print brightness
else:
    print 'Try again'

print "Good bye!"
```

Comment: The elif change fixed it on my end.  Thank you!

Comment: "The else statement prints regardless if the user enters a value that matches an if statement." This is the role of the else statement. If the if statements don't match with any of the inputs, it will always go to the else. However, with if elif else, it shouldn't go to else if an if condition is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew L. and Kalpesh Dusane answered this, thank you!!!

I needed to exchange my if for elif (else if).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

var = 1
brightness = 100

while var == 1 :  # This constructs an infinite loop

  print 'Brightness is ', brightness

  test1 = raw_input('up, down, on or off? ')

  if test1 == 'up':
     brightness = brightness + 10
     print brightness
  elif test1 == 'down':
     brightness = brightness - 10
     print brightness
  elif test1 == 'on':
     brightness = 100
     print brightness
  elif test1 == 'off':
     brightness = 0
     print brightness
  else:
     print 'Try again'

print "Good bye!"
```

The code works great, thanks!

Comment: if you don't modify `var` in any way, you can use `while True` for the same effect